# strange results from density plot

Tags: r, density-function, density-estimation

I am getting some very weird results. I have created a density plot for various continuous response variables, which are independent of each other.

[image]

I have noticed that the `Density` value seems to be very small. I know the height is meaningless and what needs to be interpreted is the area under the curve. Therefore I have tried to check the area under my curve, but I have obtained value much smaller than 1 -  namely `-15411.15`:

```
strassenverkehr.densities <-plot(density.gs8m, ylim = c(0, 0.03), col = 9, lty = 1, 
                                 xlab = "Abweichung in %", xlim = c(-100,100) )
lines(density.ks12m, col=1, col = 7, lty = 8)
lines(density.bruecke4m, col = 2,lty = 3)
lines(density.bruecke8m, col = 3,lty = 4)
lines(density.bruecke12m, col = 4,lty = 5)
lines(density.FeldwegKies, col = 5,lty = 6)
lines(density.FeldwegAsph, col = 6,lty = 7)

> density.bruecke4m <- density (diff.bruecke4m)
> trapz(density.bruecke4m$x[density.bruecke4m$x < -40])
[1] -15411.45
```

I am afraid there is something seriously wrong with my analysis. Any ideas?

Comment: That should indeed not happen. Then again, it's hard to help you if we can't recreate your problem. Can you please edit your post to contain a minimum (!) working (!) example? Thanks!

Comment: Most of your curves have a base about 100 units long and typical densities about 0.01. That checks: 100 * 0.01 = 1. The height units are not meaningless at  all: density is probability per unit deviation. That is no more meaningless than density in physical science being mass per unit volume or population density being people per unit area.

Comment: Please *describe* the calculation you're trying to do, so we can see that makes sense, and then (if it does) you can ask on a site that takes programming questions whether your code actually does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is because you wrote

```
trapz(density.bruecke4m$x[density.bruecke4m$x < -40])
```

In trapz, x and y should be supplied. Maybe try something like

```
index <- (density.bruecke4m$x < -40)
trapz(x=density.bruecke4m$x[index], y=density.bruecke4m$y[index])
```